# Windows 7 to 10 upgrade on a tablet where does it save the Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I have a tablet with only 4.08GB space on C:

**My question is where does it keep downloaded windows 10 files?**

comments appreciated

I do have a SD card of 64GB and planning on installing Program Files there but nothing installed right now so they are taking only 200MB

and Windows folder itself is 9GB

also wondering if it's possible to tell the downloader to use alternative location instead of C:

Comment: Root of system drive - `$Windows.~BT`, and `$Windows.~WS`. These are hidden folders that contain the Windows install files.

Comment: I suggest you skip trying to upgrade through Windows Update and instead, download the .ISO then mount, and install Windows 10 that way.  Windows installer is going to have a problem working from an alternate location.  You need a great deal more free space then 4 GB

Comment: @Ramhound that's what i wanted to try so i could remove all partitions even recovery etc but it doesn't boot from usb or SD i plan on opening a separate question for that later on with details screenshots of bios etc.

Comment: You have to change the boot order.  I promise you that there is a way to boot an external disk on that tablet.

Comment: posted this questions, after hours of struggle i came to conclusion maybe it just won't work http://superuser.com/questions/1063132/tw700-not-booting-from-usb-or-microsd